# Adding multiple shapes using the FLK library

Tags: c++, c, grid, shapes

I have been trying to make a checkered image.
I can print out everything just fine but I want to find a way to duplicate the shapes of different colors so that I won't have to wast time creating 64 rectangles. I really don't know where to go from here.

---

```
#include "Window.h"
#include "Graph.h"
#include "std_lib_facilities_5.h"
#include "Simple_window.h"
#include "FL/Fl_JPEG_Image.H"
int main()
try {
```

Here is the  window being create using the Simple_window struct.

```
    Point tl{ 100,100 };
    Simple_window win{ tl,440,440,"Canvas" };
```

Find the maximum distances than can be given on a window and set the values up as integers (both going in x and y dimensions). x_grid and y_grid are dimensions of a single grid square.

```
    int x_size = win.x_max();
    int y_size = win.y_max();
    int x_grid = 55;
    int y_grid = 55;
```

Use a Lines class to build the grid. For loops are made to determine where the lines will be placed to form a grid.

```
    Lines grid;
    for (int x = x_grid; x < x_size; x += x_grid) {
        grid.add(Point{ x,0 }, Point{ x,y_size });
    }
    for (int y = y_grid; y < y_size; y += y_grid) {
        grid.add(Point{ 0,y }, Point{ x_size,y });
    }
    win.attach(grid);
```

So here I created two different colors but of the same size using the rectangle class.
So right now I have placed the squared at only one point. However like I said before, I need them to be all over the image. Is there any other way besides making 64 shapes where I can have them copies of the squares? I assume there are some loops involved.

```
    Rectangle rx1(Point(55, 0), 55, 55);
    Color moss_green(fl_rgb_color(173, 223, 173));
    rx1.set_color(Color::invisible);
    rx1.set_fill_color(moss_green);
    win.attach(rx1);

    Rectangle ry1(Point(0, 0), 55, 55);
    Color cherry_blossom_pink(fl_rgb_color(255, 183, 197));
    ry1.set_color(Color::invisible);
    ry1.set_fill_color(cherry_blossom_pink);
    win.attach(ry1);

    win.wait_for_button();

    }

        catch (exception& e) {
        cerr << "exception: " << e.what() << endl;
        keep_window_open();
    }
    catch (...) {
        cerr << "exception\n";
        keep_window_open();
    }
```